# python3 numpy.setdiff1d - Wrong result using dict_keys instead of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary

```
import numpy as np

dict_to_compare = dict(A=1)
ASSUMED_KEYS = ['A','B']

direct_dict_keys_compare = np.setdiff1d(ASSUMED_KEYS, dict_to_compare.keys())
print(direct_dict_keys_compare)

<<< ['A' 'B'] <<< NOT CORRECT ( A is actually in dict_to_compare. B is missing in dict_to_compare)

list_dict_keys_compare = np.setdiff1d(ASSUMED_KEYS, list(dict_to_compare.keys()))
print(list_dict_keys_compare)

<<< ['B'] <<< CORRECT ( B is missing in dict_to_compare)
```

It looks like the reason is this:

```
>>> type(dict_to_compare.keys())
<class 'dict_keys'>
```

instead of `list`.

---

Inserted Screenshot to verify (comment)

[image]

Comment: Hi, tried your code, it is properly giving 'B' as the difference in both the cases. Alternatively, you can use below snippet to find the difference. list(set(ASSUMED_KEYS) - set(dict_to_compare.keys()))

Comment: > tried your code, it is properly giving 'B' as the difference in both the cases.
@Deepak please check screenshot.

Comment: Hi @gies0r, please don't take me otherwise, probably I ran your snippet in python2, and it worked fine. However, looks like there is a change in the way in python3. Attaching the work as answer for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information @Deepak. Strange that this is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

Python 2 supports the same code, and outputs the expected result.

[image]

In Python 3, list() has to be used, otherwise the type is dict (As you said)

[image]